# Combine nesting and rolling_origin from Tidymodels in R

Tags: r, nested, cross-validation, rolling-computation, tidymodels

I am trying to train a random forest using rolling_origin from the Tidymodels suite. I would like the folds to be exactly the months of the year. Nesting looks like it could do the trick, but tune_grid is not able to find the variables when the data is nested. How can I make this work? I put a reproducible example below.

````
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidymodels))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(yardstick))

# Create dummy data ====================================================================================================

dates <- seq(from = as.Date("2019-01-01"), to = as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = 'day' )
l <- length(dates)

set.seed(1)
data_set <- data.frame(
  date = dates,
  v1 = rnorm(l),
  v2 = rnorm(l),
  v3 = rnorm(l),
  y = rnorm(l)
)

# Random Forest Model  =================================================================================================

model <-
  parsnip::rand_forest(
    mode = "regression",
    trees = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("ranger")

# grid specification
params <-
  dials::parameters(
    trees()
  )

# Set up grid and model workflow =======================================================================================

grid <-
  dials::grid_max_entropy(
    params,
    size = 2
  )

form <- as.formula(paste("y ~ v1 + v2 + v3"))

model_workflow <-
  workflows::workflow() %>%
  add_model(model) %>%
  add_formula(form)

# Tuning on the normal data set works ====================================================================================================

data_ro_day <- data_set %>%
  rolling_origin(
    initial = 304,
    assess = 30,
    cumulative = TRUE,
    skip = 30
  )

results <- tune_grid(
  model_workflow,
  grid = grid,
  resamples = data_ro_day,
  param_info = params,
  metrics   = metric_set(mae, mape, rmse, rsq),
  control   = control_grid(verbose = TRUE))

results %>% show_best("mape", n = 2)

# Tuning on the nested data set doesn't work =========================================================================================

data_ro_month <- data_set %>%
  mutate(year_month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  nest(-year_month) %>%
  rolling_origin(
    initial = 10,
    assess = 1,
    cumulative = TRUE
  )

results <- tune_grid(
    model_workflow,
    grid = grid,
    resamples = data_ro_month,
    param_info = params,
    metrics   = metric_set(mae, mape, rmse, rsq),
    control   = control_grid(verbose = TRUE))

results$.notes ```
````

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on how you want to divide up your data for tuning, but I would recommend looking into some of the other rsample functions like `sliding_window()` and especially `sliding_period()`. They let you create experimental designs for tuning where you can fit on certain months of data and then asses on another month, sliding along all the months you have available:

```r
library(tidymodels)
dates <- seq(from = as.Date("2019-01-01"), to = as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = 'day' )
l <- length(dates)

set.seed(1)
data_set <- tibble(
  date = dates,
  v1 = rnorm(l),
  v2 = rnorm(l),
  v3 = rnorm(l),
  y = rnorm(l)
)

month_folds <- data_set %>%
  sliding_period(
    date,
    "month",
    lookback = Inf,
    skip = 4
  )

month_folds
#> # Sliding period resampling 
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   splits           id    
#>   <list>           <chr> 
#> 1 <split [151/30]> Slice1
#> 2 <split [181/31]> Slice2
#> 3 <split [212/31]> Slice3
#> 4 <split [243/30]> Slice4
#> 5 <split [273/31]> Slice5
#> 6 <split [304/30]> Slice6
#> 7 <split [334/31]> Slice7
```

I used `skip = 4` here to only keep slices where you will have more data for training. Each of these slices will training on several months of data and assess on a new, last month. The resamples slide forward through your dataset. Since I used `lookback = Inf` it always includes all past data, but you can change that.

When you have your resampling approach set up however is appropriate for your domain problem, you can then make a model specification and tune it:

```r
rf_spec <-
  rand_forest(
    mode = "regression",
    trees = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("ranger")

rf_wf <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(rf_spec) %>%
  add_formula(y ~ v1 + v2 + v3)

tune_grid(rf_wf, resamples = month_folds)
#> # Tuning results
#> # Sliding period resampling 
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   splits           id     .metrics          .notes          
#>   <list>           <chr>  <list>            <list>          
#> 1 <split [151/30]> Slice1 <tibble [20 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 2 <split [181/31]> Slice2 <tibble [20 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 3 <split [212/31]> Slice3 <tibble [20 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 4 <split [243/30]> Slice4 <tibble [20 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 5 <split [273/31]> Slice5 <tibble [20 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 6 <split [304/30]> Slice6 <tibble [20 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 7 <split [334/31]> Slice7 <tibble [20 × 5]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Julia, I didn't know about sliding_period, this works well!